# Following Javascript based href link

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I'm trying get IE to click on a link that launches a new window via JavaScript. My issue is that the link address changes pretty much every time I visit the page. *My only hope that this can work is because the link is always located in the same place.*

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with the code that would be needed to click on the link highlighted below:

Here is the HTML: The last line is the line that isth

```
<div id="panelTitle">
<img src="/art/nav/clearpixel.gif" width="10" height="7" style="display: block;"/>
<div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#bec7de" width="100%">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td width="100%">
<script language="javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"/>
<script language="javascript" src="/js/wm/reptop/Details.js"/>
<script language="javascript" src="/js/wm/reptop/common.js"/>
<script language="javascript" src="/js/caos/caos.js"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td class="snl" width="50%">
<td class="sn">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<tr valign="top">
<td class="sn">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#cccccc" valign="LEFT">
<tr valign="top">
<td class="snl" width="50%">
<td class="sn">
<a href="javascript:fnOpenWindow('/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?111111111')">Dr
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: The code I have so far is at work, but it's pretty long and filled with random sensitive data that I would need to take out before posting. I can do it tomorrow though if requested - though there isn't much that would be learned from what I have. 
@pnuts I checked out that site. Are you hinting that I should not have included the VBA in the title?
I'm sad to say I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, but it's a hyperlink so it is highlighted in blue. I know how to focus on the new window this link would open, just not how to click it since it changes (not that I would know otherwise)

Comment: Ahh I understand. I will apply this for next time. Thank you!

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to have your code *'filled with random sensitive data'* but I must admit that makes a great excuse for not posting original effort.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it is generally better to use `parentWindow.execScript` that trying to 'click' an anchor element.

It doesn't appear that the anchor element you are trying to 'click' has any form of unique identification so you might have to loop through all of the `<a>` elements looking for it.

```
Dim sHREF As String, a As Long

For a = 0 To ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a").Length - 1
    sHREF = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a")(a).href
    If CBool(InStr(1, sHREF, "popuppartyinfo", vbTextCompare)) Then
        ie.document.parentWindow.execScript sHREF
        Do While ie.busy Or ie.readystart < READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        Exit For
    End If
Next a
```

There may be a more definitive way of identifying the desired `<a>` link but the above should give you the gist of the process.